# How to allow perl cgi-bin script to run system commands?

Tags: apache, perl, permission-denied, cgi-bin

I'm currently working on developing a perl script as a cgi-bin in my website.

I successfully config it to run without any issues. Here are the config I have done for it.

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /my web directory/cgi-bin/
    <Directory /my web directory/cgi-bin/>
        Options ExecCGI
        AddHandler cgi-script cgi pl
    </Directory>
```

But I cannot use system() function in the script to run some system commands.
It gives Can't exec, No such file or directory
or Permission denied.

What should add you apache config to allow cgi-bin to run those commands?

Thank you!

Comment: how are you using `system()`?  Are you including the path, e.g.: `system('/bin/ls')` or just `system('ls')`?  If the latter, chances are very good that the environment simply doesn't have a path.

Comment: And if it's running in a `chroot` jail, chances are the binary doesn't exist inside the jail

Comment: Hi @PaulProgrammer, Well I just tried both system('ls') and system('/bin/ls') commands and both are working without issue. What I'm currently doing is trying to run system("/var/lib/asterisk/bin/module_admin", "reload") or system("amportal a r"). These are reload command for freepbx asterisk service.  my script own by asterisk:asterisk, and /var/lib/asterisk/bin/module_admin also the same.

Comment: That means that you're probably just not locating your executable correctly.

Comment: Can you post the results of ls -l /var/lib/asterisk/bin ?  Apache is probably running as a user who doesn't have permissions to execute module_admin.  The solution might be as simple as adding execute permission to that executable for group and all, e.g. chmod +x /var/lib/asterisk/bin/module_admin - though there are security implications of this.  Don't do that if you're not sure that you want any user on the system to be able to run module_admin.

Comment: @ratsbane Thanks for your reply.
Perrmission was 730 for the /var/lib/asterisk/bin/module_admin. I gave 731 but no luck. Both files are owned my asterisk user. I wonder by which user get run my perl script when I run it from web url.
Can't exec "/var/lib/asterisk/bin/module_admin": Permission denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Found the problem and fixed.

Steps I followed:

```
apt-get install apache2-suexec-custom
a2enmod suexec
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Then go to website apache config and added `SuexecUserGroup asterisk asterisk`
in here asterisk is the use that I didn't have the permission to run commands.

Then go to `/etc/apache2/suexec/www-data` and you will see 2 un-comment lines. We need to give correct absolute path for cgi-bin and alias path for the cgi-bin. By default it have `/var/www` and `public_html/cgi-bin`.

That's it. This fixed my problem.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html recommends not using suexec at all unless you "know what you're doing" (which I never do).